# Is it fundamentally wrong to write a CPU intensive client side HTML5 application?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

It is possible and sensible to plan on writing a client side HTML5 Application that will be doing some CPU intensive calculations? (Image processing)

I know that it's usually has been the standard to offload calculations to the server but since there are new options with HTML5 i'm wondering if we could actually write a full app that will run in the browser.

If I understand correctly, web workers can help with multi-threading tasks but I have no deep knowledge of how that exactly works.

Again, I'm looking for leads on how to approach this, if at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible? Yes. Sensible? Eh, as long as it doesn't lock up the browser.

Comment: HMTL5 -> Web Workers! Now, since you *know* about them, *go read some* and follow through with tutorials/examples - this is why I down-voted. Although, any task that can be written as some form of queue and doesn't need to be synchronous is easy enough to "spread out over time" (i.e. with chained setTimeouts) to avoid negatively impacting browsing.

Comment: @user2864740 I wasn't asking how to user web workers. I was offering it as a possible solution and asking for others and a possible advice. I did read about web workers and I know how they work. I'm just not sure they are the way to go.

Comment: Then this entire question is pointless because Web Workers were *obviously* introduced to solve a problem ..  like performing calculations on the client without blocking the main code. Either that or someone was like, hey, let's make something entirely useless and call it Web Workers!

Comment: The practical use of Web Workers for your particular problem is then for *you* to decided based on lots of external factors (including preference). There is no problem here. There is no suitable SO question here. And you *have* your leads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not fundamentally wrong. Client machines typically have a lot of processing power, and this power is at the browsers disposal. Just make sure you write your app in such a way that it has a good user experience!

Web workers will allow your UI JavaScript to run while you number-crunch on another thread. This sounds quite appropriate for your task.

Also, by doing this client-side your app no longer depends on the network connectivity to the server. With image processing I would expect that there will be a lot of data passing from client to server, which could be quite slow.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's perfectly okay to write client-side applications, that are moderately heavy. But, keep a eye on the kind of users you are targeting your web-application to. If those users are running modern computers, some basic image-processing is just fine.

One design pattern I would suggest is if a task takes more than 2 seconds to complete on a client computer, just designate the work to the server and show a processing animation on the browser. If the task will complete within 2 seconds, you can do it on the client-side. If your script makes the users' computer slow for more than 2 seconds, it's very likely that they will notice the slow-down and will start hating your web application.

If the image to be processed is a large one, convert it to a low-resolution one and do all the processing on the low-resolution one so it is not so processing intensive. But, you'll need to keep an exact log of all the operations the user is performing. Once the user is happy, send the log to the server and let the server do the heavy work on the high-resolution image.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. It is perfectly fine to perform an operation that takes > 2 secs client-side. Just as long as the UI remains rather responsive. Web workers are a potential solution.

Comment: If this were a desktop image processing app would you perform image processing server side? Or a video editing app? No! Web apps are no different, as far as your user is concerned they are both just apps.

Comment: @ColinE I completely agree with you. It's perfectly fine to have the entire computing to be done the client's computer. But, me being a start-up person, know how hard it is to get users to like your application. My ideas were only meant to make this application better. If the load is divided, people can use the website, even on tablets.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, it's even been done but whether it's a good idea or not depends entirely on the context - who's going to be using it, what browsers would it need to support, what devices would it need to run on.

Should you want to go ahead, one thing to checkout would be [asm.js](http://asmjs.org/) it's a subset of javascript (so it works in all browsers) that browsers can optimize very well for (I think just Firefox right now) you can either code as if to the metal in it or more sensibly use it as a compile target - so you can write in another language (say C++) - and compile to something that'll run very fast in the browser.